# UTF-8 Character edit is not OK in output window

Tags: c, putty

I have configured My putty to accept UTF-8 Character
[image: Putty configuration]

I have set the linux environmental variable as UTF-8.

```
export LANG="en_GB.UTF-8"
```

How ever when I run my program, edit my use input the I have 2 press backspace key twice to delete the single character even though if the environmental values in active state.

Also I tried and I could not able to set the environmental value through my c code .

```
if (setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8") == NULL) {
    abort();
    }
```

what I have to do to get this problem solved?

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Please ask a separate question instead of drastically changing the current one.